# Call localhost from c# solution

Tags: c#, api, c#-4.0, asp.net-web-api

I am able to connect to the API from postman as I have already built the solution locally and created a virtual directory.

URL looks something like this:
http://localhost/myservice/api/***

But now when I am trying to consume the above api using my c# solution, I am getting 404 resource not found.

While I see the request uri looks good. RequestUri: 'http://localhost/myservice/api/**' same as the above.

I am trying to do this for the first time for debugging purpose. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You'll have to show the request code for us to have any chance at seeing the issue.

Comment: Have you set the Web API as the `Startup Project` in your Visual Studio solution? After you have done that, have you pressed `F5` within Visual Studio ?

Comment: Web API solution is working great. Due to which I am able to get response from postman. But, this web API is consumed in another solution (xyz) through which I want to debug. Hence, I am sending request from xyz.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Here is the response {StatusCode: 404, ReasonPhrase: 'Not Found', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:
{
  Cache-Control: private
  Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 23:00:11 GMT
  Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
  Content-Length: 4877
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
}}

Comment: @BradleyDotNET Here is the request {Method: POST, RequestUri: http://localhost/***, Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StringContent, Headers:
{
  Accept: application/json
  Authorization: xyz*****************
  Authorization: xyz*****************
  Date: Wed, 09 Aug 2017 22:57:39 GMT
  Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
  Content-Length: 1911
}}

Comment: Strongly suggest that you use the debugger, breakpoint on the request object (before submitted), breakpoint the response (which I guess we sort of know is going to be a 404 at this point, but could still tell you stuff), and figure out where the difference is, between Postman and your client application. Also remember that Postman request headers are at times different from headers that you send from your client application. Basically, **scrutinize everything**.

Comment: I did that for some time but it seems better to go back and spend some more time scrutinizing. Thanks!

Comment: @Vicky, I would suggest you to edit your question and provide more information so we can help. Things like Action signature from the controller, if the integration is through code (c#), the code calling the API. There are a bunch of things that can be happening. Regards.

Comment: Thank you all especially @code4life as I found there was issue in the parameters being passed. One the property which was the resource was incorrect.

Comment: @Vicky: glad that you were able to find it out! And... welcome to the wacky and weird world of multi-layered debugging, LOL!

Answer (score 0):

does the api has a baseaddress in webconfig? if so try removing it and run the solution. then copy the url and to your other c# solution